# Using Sequelize to add values into database

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get a object from browser and trying to store the value in the database, for which i am using sequelize concept to store the values, but i get the error

```
throw new Error('Unrecognized data type for field ' + name);
Error: Unrecognized data type for field name
    at rawAttributes._.mapValues (C:\Java Related\Node\Grijan Project 1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:803:15
```

my index.js is

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename = path.basename(module.filename);
var config = require('../config.json');
var db = {};
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.name,config.username,config.password,config);

fs
.readdirSync(__dirname)
.filter(function (file){
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
})
.forEach(function(file){
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
})

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
      db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

i cant find the error since it does not point to the files that i have created.

Comment: Post your contents inside models directory, show the relevant code where you are trying to save these values

Comment: @AkhilThayyil Bro thanks, i solved it, i made a error in my Person model, Saved the fields of database as name : datatypes.String but should have saved it by name : datatypes.String